# "Run time-error 13: Type Mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA program which lets user enter names (integers/strings/etc.) into first row of active Excel sheet to write titles. After the inputs are written, I need to write the outputs in the adjacent cells.

Stepping through macro line by line, I believe this is the problem line which gives the error

> Run time-error 13: Type Mismatch

```
Cells(1, counter + inputnum) = outputnum
```

This is the relevant function:

```
Sub enteroutputs()
title = "K-Map Program"
outputnum = Application.InputBox("How many outputs?", title)
If IsNumeric(outputnum) = False Then
    problem = "output"
    Call notnum
End If

For counter = 1 To outputnum
    outputnum = Application.InputBox("Enter output name.", title)
    Cells(1, counter + inputnum) = outputnum
Next
Dim ok
ok = MsgBox("Enter outputs in " & ActiveSheet.Name & " .", vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

inputnum is defined in the function which executes before this function:

```
Sub enterinputs()
title = "K-Map Program"
inputnum = Application.InputBox("How many inputs?", title)
If IsNumeric(inputnum) = False Then
    problem = "input"
    Call notnum
End If

For counter = 1 To inputnum
    inputnum = Application.InputBox("Enter input name.", title)
    Cells(1, counter) = inputnum
Next
Call enteroutputs
```

End Sub

Comment: Yet another bug that could have been prevented with `Option Explicit` forcing you to declare the variables you're using: `Dim inputnum As Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply missed something

```
Sub enterinputs()
title = "K-Map Program"
inputnum = Application.InputBox("How many inputs?", title)
If IsNumeric(inputnum) = False Then
    problem = "input"
    Call notnum
End If
' ~~~~ here inputnum is numeric  ~~~~ 
For counter = 1 To inputnum
    inputnum = Application.InputBox("Enter input name.", title) ' ~~~~ here inputnum is not! ~~~~ 
    Cells(1, counter) = inputnum
Next
Call enteroutputs 'while inputnum is NOT numeric
Exit Sub
```

just add between `Next` and `Call enteroutputs`:

```
inputnum = counter - 1
```